# WHERE clause with SET and UPDATE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, where-clause

I have to start that there are many examples here, but none of them works with multiple (in my case 3) tables, which I have to use.

The idea of this is: when I update one of my tables (things), I want my trigger to automaticly update another table (current) with multiplied value of 2 columns (salary from dudes table, and thing_cost from things) into a column curr_cash.

I want it to look like:

```
Money : Date : Id1 (id of person) : Id2 (Id of thing)
```

Example:

```
400 03-12-12 34 3
300 03-12-12 34 2
400 03-12-12 4 3
```

and so on.

Currently what my trigger does is to sum uo everything and associate it to a person who bought something.. fail logic.

here is code of my trigger:

```
create trigger money after update on `things`
for each row
begin
SET @c1 = (SELECT sum(`thing_cost`) from `things`);
SET @c2 = (SELECT sum(`salary`) from `dude_base`);
UPDATE `current` SET `curr_cash` = @c1 * @c2 / 100
end;
$$
```

I need to add something like this instead of sum:

```
WHERE id2 from things = id2 from current AND WHERE id1 from dude_base = is1 from current
```

But my syntax fail miserably. I work on MySQL on xampp (phpmyadmin).

To sum up,
I have to know what a dude bought (exact id), and what thing (exact id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE `current` c 
INNER JOIN things    t ON c.id2 = t.id2
INNER JOIN dude_base d ON d.id1 = c.is1
SET c.`curr_cash` = t.thing_cost * d.salary / 100;
```